# Error pages shown in jquery modal popup asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, popup

And I am using this for loading a popup:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("<div></div>")
                .addClass("dialog")
                .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
                .appendTo("body")
                .dialog({
                    title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                    close: function () { $(this).remove(); },
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true
                })
                .load(this.href);
        });
```

The problem is when I click any link that will open in the popup and any errors occurs the whole error page is loaded into popup.
I want the user to be redirected to unauthorized or any other error pages instead of loading error pages into the modal popup.

This works fine for any links that will not opens in popup.

FYI,
I have enabled custom error mode.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Errors/General/">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/Http404/" /> 
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 2):

Call .load() first to load the content and detect errors, then invoke the dialog. For example:

```
var dialog = $('<div></div>');
dialog.load('url', function (response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        alert("Something went wrong opening the dialog.");
    } else {
        dialog.dialog();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice answer - short and sweet.  This us better UX, too.  Otherwise, it's popup, chug chug, content ... or popup, chug chug, oops, error, close popup, redirect.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't helps me. I am still getting the error, and unauthorized page in the dialog. It seems that the user is unauthorized for the controller action and the asp.net routes to unauthorized page and the whole page loads into popup. And there was no any error status that ajax can found.

Comment: Make sure you aren't rendering something in the layout that requires authorization. From: http://serverfault.com/questions/137073/401-unauthorized-on-server-2008-r2-iis-7-5

Comment: @SteveAndrews Yup, I am rendering something in the layout that requires authorization. The problem was not that. I just want the unauthorized and other pages not to be loaded on the jquery modal popup when something wrong happens i.e user is unauthorized or error occurred when processing your request.

Comment: @BIKALBHATTARAI that is on **Controller** side....on what kind of implementation of security you will do..on how you will return that error message on **View**..